# raspberry pi opencv video window dosen't show properly

Tags: python, opencv, video, raspberry-pi, video-processing

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
import imutils

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640,480))


time.sleep(0.1)

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    image = frame.array
    #cv2.imshow("frame", image)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame.array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)[1]
    #cv2.imshow("Gray", gray)

    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    #cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)

    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
    output = thresh.copy()

    cv2.imshow("frame", image)
    cv2.imshow("Gray", gray)
    cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

Hey guys I am running opencv 3.3.0 on python 3.5.3 on a raspberry pi 3 b+ running raspbian when I run the above code in a virtual environment with opencv it compiles and runs but does not work as intended. The frame window shows up and updates fine but the gray and thresh frames open and then the width become close to 0. I attached a photo of it If anyone has any insight that would be great.[desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7MMP.png)

Comment: can you try waitKey(100)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

`gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame.array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)[1]`

to simply

`gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame.array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: Thank you that worked one question though. What does that [1] do?

Comment: The image is loaded as an array of arrays(lists in case of Python). When you write `[1]` in front of the array of arrays, only the first array is utilised and not the entire system. Thus, it was messing up your code. You can print the result by typing `print(gray)` both, with and without the `[1]` and see the result for yourself. If you like my answer and if it helped, kindly accept this as the best answers so people can know that the question has been answered and it can help others too :)